# Advanced SQL to Analyze Records and Report in Columns

Tags: sql

I have a, rather perceived, complex situation. My table structure is as below:

[image]

Now I require the results as below:
Top Products by Country (Based on Count of Selections)
R1,2.. represent respondents who selected options

[image]

Kindly help me with the SQL Logic required to get this output.

Thanks for all the great help.

Regards,
Navs

Comment: What have you tried already? Are you in control of the source table structure?

Comment: I have tried to use union to aggregate results by Country, but couldn't get values by country in columns (i.e, my current results are just 2 columns - country and top products)--but I would wish the countries to be in the columns and products listed. Also, I am not in control of the table structure.

Comment: If you know the countries and products in advance you can always do something like sum(Soap_Usage) grouped by a specific country and have a case when sum(Soap_Usage) > 0 then 'Soap Usage' else null end (for each country and each product). However, I have to say that the second table looks rather weird to me ... Why would you want that?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax depend on your variety of SQL, but the principle is

1. Unpivot your source data into a normalised form
2. Total the amounts, and rank them
3. Pivot them on the country to get columnar data.